# How to get rid of space in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, whitespace

I am trying to take a string in a list of strings and remove all the white space while separating non-space with a comma. For example I have the string:

```
'        XX       XX          X   XXXXXX   XX               XXXXXXX    XXXXX'
```

and need to return it as `['XX', 'XX', 'X', 'XXXXXX', 'XX', 'XXXXXXX', 'XXXXX']`. Any suggestions?

Note: The amount of space between each segment varies.

Comment: `str.split` is your friend.

Comment: Just to clarify - you mean you want to return it as a list, rather than a string such as "[XX, XX, X, XXXXXX, XX, XXXXXXX, XXXXX]"?

Comment: It is already in a list. The brackets aren't really necessary.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), it does *exactly* what you need already, splitting on arbitrary-width whitespace:

```
>>> example = '        XX       XX          X   XXXXXX   XX               XXXXXXXX    XXXXX'
>>> example.split()
['XX', 'XX', 'X', 'XXXXXX', 'XX', 'XXXXXXXX', 'XXXXX']
```

Note that the leading whitespace has been removed as well.

Quoting the documentation:

> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't get any simpler than this:

```
my_string.split()
```

Example:

```
>>> '        XX       XX          X   XXXXXX   XX  '.split()
['XX', 'XX', 'X', 'XXXXXX', 'XX']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it:

```
s =  s = '        XX       XX          X   XXXXXX   XX               XXXXXXXX    XXXXX'
print s.split() # prints ['XX', 'XX', 'X', 'XXXXXX', 'XX', 'XXXXXXXX', 'XXXXX']
```